# Calculate a % complete based on dates and numbers

Tags: excel

I'm trying to find the % of a quantity complete based on a determined start date and a forecasted end date. 
EX:

```
Start Date        End Date            Total Qty     Qty Complete     % Complete

11/12/16           4/2/17               855               305
```

I'm a novice where excel is concerned and really only know basic functions and calculations. I've searched on here and within excel and can't seem to find a formula that works.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `=(TODAY()-A2)/(B2-A2)`

Comment: Actually, if your problem is to find the %, you just have to do `Qty Complete / Total Qty`. I'm assuming it would be `D2/C2`

Comment: Do Excel formulas qualify as "programming" or is this already off-topic as it's not related to programming?

Comment: @Robert this has been discussed in great detail on meta.  The current consensus is that, yes Formulas are just another language and is in fact programming and on topic here.  But you will always have those that disagree.

Comment: @ScottCraner I can see it being on topic for complex formulas, but some simple basic operations?

Comment: @Robert what is basic to one is complicated for another.  Were I agree with you on this one.  This is more a math problem than it is an Excel problem.